# Match a block of text enclosed by newlines that contains a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Given the text:

```
text text 
texttexttext text BOB
text


text
texttt text
text


text text text 
tBOBext
texttexttext text
text 
text


text text text 
text
texttexttext text
text
```

What would be the reggex that would match:

```
text text 
texttexttext text BOB
text
```

and

```
text text text 
tBOBext
texttexttext text
text 
text
```

Am taking it step by step first trying to identify a pattern for matching any block of text surrounded by a newline on both sides. Am hoping to add the `BOB` filter after that.

I'm currently at `^\n(\n|.)*?^$`.  It doesn't match the ending newline, and also has matches on empty lines without any text.

[Reggex editor with this example](https://regex101.com/r/VXfacC/3)

Comment: I have posted the question following all the suggested best practices for regex related questions. Please provide info for the down votes.

Comment: Actually, I upvoted because of the clarity. But I guess the reason might be _not enough attempts to resolve your own problem_, or [no research](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:.+\R)*^.*?BOB.*\R(?:^.+\R)*
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXfacC/9)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Match start
- `(?:.+\R)*`: Match 0 or more lines with at least 1 character
- `^.*?BOB.*\R`: Match a line with `BOB` somewhere
- `(?:^.+\R)*`: Match 0 or more lines with at least 1 character

[image: regexp img]

---

If you are fine with lookahead then you may also use this regex:

```
^(?=(?:.+\R)*.*?BOB)(?:.+\R)+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/VXfacC/7)

Comment: Do `(?:^.+\n)*` and `(?:^.+$)*` mean the same?

Comment: `$` is zero width assertion like `^` so it won't match a newline.

Comment: I have updated it further. Using `\R` is more portable than using `\n` to match any newline

Comment: @anubhava I don't think it's better to use `\R`. I have seen that most of the flavors like 'js','python' aren't using this, instead, they use `\n`

Comment: @RamireddySamar: Since question is for perl regex hence `\R` was suggested. If it was for JS/Python etc then it would have been `[\r\n]+` to match all kind of newlines.

Comment: @anubhava: What do you mean by **Portable**?, I didn't get you.

Comment: By portability, I mean different OS with their different editors. Windows uses `\r\n`, Unix uses `\n` and OSX used to have `\r` as line break